# How to detect which feature is under zoom focus when a map is zoomed in/out in leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to implement an interactive map, on click of the initial map say "district-wise" map, a "blockwise" map is loaded. The click event is working fine because I can find out the sourceTarget and feature which is clicked.

But what if I have to toggle between "district-wise" and "blockwise" maps on the zoom events, I am not able to get a find a focused district (feature) to load the second map for that feature.

I am binding zoom event as shown below:

```
map.on('zoom', whenMapZoolLevelChanged);
```

the function that is triggered on the zoom event:

```
 function whenMapZoolLevelChanged(e)
        {
            if(mapLevel === "d" && e.type === "zoom" && e.sourceTarget._zoom > 10)
            { 
                console.log(e.sourceTarget);
            }
        }
```

However on click event I am refreshing the maps as shown below:

```
function whenDistrictLayerClicked(e) {
            var distId = e.sourceTarget.feature.properties.ID_;
            map.remove();
            drawBlockMap(distId, e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);
        }
```

Kindly help if there is any way to get the focused feature when the zoom in event is triggered.